# How to create a view that lists all groups and their respective contents?

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I have used `organic groups` to implement the 'group' & 'group content' functionality.

I have a *group* content type.
And, I have a *group content* content type.

How can I create a view that lists all groups' titles and their respective contents' titles clubbed together with that group?

For eg.

If,

*Group 1* has 2 content types: *C1 & C2*,

*Group 2* has 2 content types: *C3, C4 & C5*,

*Group 3* has 2 content types: *C6*,

*Group 4* has 2 content types: *C7 & C8*,

Then expected result is:

1. Group 1: C1, C2
2. Group 1: C3, C4 & C5
3. Group 1: C6
4. Group 1: C7, C8

Answer (score 0):

- Create a view that lists all content of type "Group Content"
- Add a relationship OG membership: Group Node from OG membership and make it mandatory

[image]
 - Add field Group Title and exclude it from display choose relationship above

[image]

- Use Group By Option in Display settings and group by Group Title

[image]

And the output will be

[image]

Find view export below.. Content type names are group and group_content

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'group_group_content';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Group - Group Content';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Group - Group Content';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'field' => 'title_1',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: OG membership: Group Node from OG membership */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_membership_related_node_group']['id'] = 'og_membership_related_node_group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_membership_related_node_group']['table'] = 'og_membership';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_membership_related_node_group']['field'] = 'og_membership_related_node_group';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['og_membership_related_node_group']['required'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['id'] = 'title_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['relationship'] = 'og_membership_related_node_group';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['label'] = 'Group';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'group_content' => 'group_content',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'group---group-content';
```